# Get DOM from webpage in python

Tags: python, dom, cookies, setcookie

hello guys i'm wondering how to get DOM from web page !
so check out this
Example.com>Get Dom>Get Document from Dom > Get Cookie Values from Document

i tried this code but not working

```
response.urllib2.urlopen('http://Example.com')
print response.info().getheader("cookie")
```

also i tried print `response.read()`

but it's ouput None for `print response.info().getheader("cookie")`

i tried `Set-Cookie` i got values but not exact same from the broswer !! i open the web via webtext editor (Firebug) and i got diffrent information so i'm confused is Set-Cookie equal to cookie
i dunno please give me some suggest

Comment: confusing. cookies are not in the DOM, they are in the header, as the code indicates. are you really going to example.com? is it setting a cookie?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. As mentioned above, the DOM and cookies are separate concerns. If you wish to write a web client and in the process you need to handle cookies and access the DOM, say so, then we can help you.

Comment: jcomeau_ictx  < no i'm trying here https://signup.live.com/checkavail.aspx?chkavail=homo123443@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

There is [something here](http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?17) about HTTP Cookies with Python. You might actually be better off using / learning about python's httplib / http.client [documented here](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html), that would allow you to simulate / build an http client. Or even use the more generic urllib [documented here](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), that handle more protocols / arbitrary resources, and with it say you can access headers via the `urllib.urlretrieve` method is there were any.

Comment: i get header `print response.info()` but there is no thing !!